# Upload video from link to youtube

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I have a video asset link that when visited downloads the video locally. My question is using the youtube api, am I able to directly upload the video from the link?

For example, in the docs it says to:

```
mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('HelloWorld.MP4')
service.videos().insert(
 //
)
```

I would like too:

```
mediaUrl = MediaFileUpload('https://production.assets.clips.cdn/path')
service.videos().insert(
 //
)
```

Is this possible with the api? Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your question is *negative*: the upload procedure works only for files that belong to the machine initiating the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API call. That's because the initiator of the API call *has to send itself the actual bytes of the file he/she needs uploaded*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm hosting this on heroku and I want it to upload some videos, if I can't have the files locally is it possible to automate this?

Comment: Then, for each file hosted on Heroku that you want uploaded to YouTube, you need to first download it to the computer initiating the *Videos.insert* API call.